# Impact of altering Oracle Sequence on existing data, specifically 'START WITH' value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am in a situation in which I am working with a Oracle database. One of the tables in our database was incomplete was another branch was tracking their data in an Excel spreadsheet. After reformatting their data I was able to successfully append the data to the Oracle table. One of the steps I had to take in order to accomplish this was to manually assign new DISPOSAL_ID (the primary key for this particular table). My approach to this was to simply take the maximum value for DISPOSAL_ID for that table and increment by one for each new record I wished to append.

The problem now is that an end user is reporting that which she tries to enter a new record into that table she receives an error message from the Oracle APEX application: ORA - 00001: Unique constraint (table_name.PK) violated.

I suspect this has to do with the fact that the Oracle sequence generating primary keys for this table is yielding values that I had manually assigned when I appended the branch data to the table.

What should I do to update to update the sequence?
The current sequence definition is:
CREATE SEQUENCE   "MP_DISPOSAL_EVENTS_SEQ1"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 861 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION
/

If I replace the 'START WITH' value with the new maximum value for the DISPOSAL_ID will this resolve the issue? Will it have any impacts on the existing data? I apologize for the novice nature of this question but I am relatively new to this and have no one technical to support me in this venture. I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do an `alter sequence` to change the starting value.  You can drop and re-create the sequence with a new starting value.  The primary downside to that is that if there are any grants on the sequence, those grants will be lost and would need to be re-granted.

It would generally be better to change the increment, get the `nextval` of the sequence, and then set the increment back to 1.  So, for example, if you added 150 new rows to the table

```
alter sequence MP_DISPOSAL_EVENTS_SEQ1 increment by 150;
select MP_DISPOSAL_EVENTS_SEQ1.nextval from dual
alter sequence MP_DISPOSAL_EVENTS_SEQ1 increment by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never make a habbit of using a sequence number as a primary KEY for the very reason you mentioned.

I prefer using an IDENTITY column associated with each table so you can uniquely identify a single row. In addition, that's one less object in your table.

```
create table t1(
      seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
….
….
```

Create a temporary table with the IDENTITY column. Load it with a SELECT and rename the table. You will never have the problem again.

Going forward for new tables you may want to incorporate this feature. Good luck

Comment: an identity is nothing but a sequence and associated trigger, wrapped up and placed under the covers.